# Как мне распаковать координаты, что бы можно было подставить в функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список с координатами
Я его распаковываю с помощью *args, получаю два tuple для x и y,
далее мне нужно их использовать в данном цикле, но как мне взять координату и отрисовать то что нужно, не совсем понимаю

```
list_point = [(100, 200), (300, 350), (400, 500)]
x, y = zip(*list_point)

while True:
    point = sd.get_point(x, y)
    sd.start_drawing()
    y -= 10
    x += 5
    sd.snowflake(*point, length=50, color=sd.background_color)
    point = sd.get_point(x, y)
    sd.snowflake(point, length=50)
    sd.finish_drawing()
    sd.sleep(0.1)
    if y < -40:
        break
    if sd.user_want_exit():
        break


sd.pause()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_point = [(100, 200), (300, 350), (400, 500)]

for x, y in list_point:
    point = sd.get_point(x, y)
    sd.start_drawing()
    y -= 10
    x += 5
    sd.snowflake(*point, length=50, color=sd.background_color)
    point = sd.get_point(x, y)
    sd.snowflake(point, length=50)
    sd.finish_drawing()
    sd.sleep(0.1)
    if y < -40:
        break
    if sd.user_want_exit():
        break


sd.pause()
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать так, спасибо

```
for x, y in list_point:
    while True:
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.start_drawing()
        y -= 10
        x += + 5
        sd.snowflake(point, length=50, color=sd.background_color)
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.snowflake(point, length=50)
        sd.finish_drawing()
        sd.sleep(0.1)
        if y < -40:
            break
        if sd.user_want_exit():
            break
```